# which way is correct? Javascript Objects (nodejs)

Tags: javascript, node.js, javascript-objects, ecmascript-5

I love javascript and Node, but when i declare Objects.. i don't know what is best practice and high performance. Im interest high performance.

```
"use strict";

module.exports = SignUpBusiness;
SignUpBusiness.__proto__ = new SignUpBusiness;


function SignUpBusiness(){

    this._certificate   = null;
    this._db            = require('mongoose');
    this._model         = require('../models/User.js');
    this._userModel     = this._db.model('User', this._model.UserSchema);
    this._result        = false;

    this.runLoginProcess = function(credentials , next){
         //code
    }

    // etc.

}
```

Or this way:

```
"use strict";
module.exports = {

    _certificate   : null,
    _db            : require('mongoose'),
    _model         : require('../models/User.js'),
    _userModel     : this._db.model('User', this._model.UserSchema),
    _result        : false,


    runLoginProcess: function(credentials , next){
          //code
    }
    // etc.
}
```

Thanks a lot! 
And.. sorry for my English.

Comment: I prefer the 1st one, makes it easier to get the right scope.

Comment: Will you be creating this object once, or many times?

Comment: Only be created once and exported to module.exports in NodeJS. The controller calls the business layer (this code) to perform a complex process.

Comment: Sergio has the best answer so far: "It depends." However, (no offense to Sergio) there's more to it than what he writes. So there is not *one* way which is *correct*, and the other *incorrect*. I've used both methods, depending on context. (I say neither are incorrect but both examples *currently* present in the question contain problematic or downright faulty code. For instance, ``this._db.model('User', this._model.UserSchema)`` in the second example does not do anything sensible.)

Comment: The answer "it depends" is not good, there is always a better way. Perhaps the problem is that I give few details on the operation of the code. Im sorry.
I like the 2 ways, but I am looking for is **the best performance** without sacrificing a beautiful and **understandable code**. 

Why is problematic line of code? @Louis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using prototypes (the first choice) is the best way. Prototypes are best practice and reduce memory consumption (otherwise you'll redeclare the memory on each new object).

According to Louis, the above may be inaccurate:

> If the module's export is assigned to foo, then foo.**proto**._*proto*_.**proto** is defined, but foo.**proto**._*proto*_.**proto**._*proto*_ is not. The second choice has a depth of 1: foo.**proto** is defined but not any deeper. Not only is the first case taking more memory but it is also slower because field lookups will have to traverse a deeper chain.

I cannot test this for my own answer right now. I will try to later.

Comment: It depends on the situation. There are reasons to use either, in particular if your object is going to be a singleton the memory issue is not relevant. That said, if it's not immediately intuitive to you which choice you should make, use the prototype method, it's more flexible, and it will teach you how and when to make that choice.

Comment: The way the first choice is defined it has a depth of 3 objects. That is, if the module's export is assigned to ``foo``, then ``foo.__proto__.__proto__.__proto__`` is defined, but ``foo.__proto__.__proto__.__proto__.__proto__`` is not. The second choice has a depth of 1: ``foo.__proto__`` is defined but not any deeper. Not only is the first case taking *more* memory but it is also *slower* because field lookups will have to traverse a deeper chain. (Even name hits will be slower but the explanation is too long for this comment.)

Comment: How is it assigned with a depth of three objects?

Comment: That's how the JavaScript VM constructs it. Try it in Node.js.

Comment: I'll be able to test it after lunch. Until then, I'll make a note of it in my answer. If you want to explain how name hits and field lookups will be slower in detail, feel free to post an answer.

Comment: Once you can try it, try the following: ``foo.hasOwnProperty("_db")``. You'll get ``false``. Then ``foo.__proto__.hasOwnProperty("_db")``. You'll get ``true``. This tells you that all the fields we actually care about are not on the object *directly* exported by the module but on its prototype. So the VM has to walk up at least one level to get the fields we care about. In the second module example, all the fields are directly on the exported object.

Comment: Actually, the second one gave me `TypeError: Cannot call method 'hasOwnProperty' of undefined`. Does node.js have documentation on prototype handling?